# Convert multiple csv to another csv format

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert my old CSV files to another format and a new name (`_new.csv`). All files are in the folder with the date stamp. e.g `Filename_05_08_2021.csv`. Almost I have 63 files from today date to back. The problem is I have to provide each file name one by one while call function. Is there any way I can convert all of them? I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
def new_csv(file_path):
    c = csv.reader(open(file_path))
    c_list = []
    c_list.extend(c)
    out_csv = open(file_path.replace('.csv','_new.csv'), "w")
    for line in c_list:
        if len(line) == 10:
            out_csv.write(str(line[0]+','+line[1]+','+(line[2]).upper()+','+''+','+
            (line[3][1:]).upper()+','+line[4]+','+line[5]+','+
            line[6]+','+line[7]+','+line[9])+'\n')
        
        if len(line) > 10:
            out_csv.write(str(line[0]+','+line[1]+','+(line[2]).upper()+','+
                          (line[3][1:]).upper()+','+line[4][1:]+','+line[5]+','+
                          line[6]+','+line[7]+','+line[8]+','+line[10])+'\n')
    out_csv.close()        
    
    print ("new .csv written")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_csv('C:\\Myfolder\\Filename_05_08_2021.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate within the directory. You can use glob:

```
import glob
def new_csv(file_path):
    c = csv.reader(open(file_path))
    c_list = []
    c_list.extend(c)
    out_csv = open(file_path.replace('.csv','_new.csv'), "w")
    for line in c_list:
        if len(line) == 10:
            out_csv.write(str(line[0]+','+line[1]+','+(line[2]).upper()+','+''+','+
            (line[3][1:]).upper()+','+line[4]+','+line[5]+','+
            line[6]+','+line[7]+','+line[9])+'\n')
        
        if len(line) > 10:
            out_csv.write(str(line[0]+','+line[1]+','+(line[2]).upper()+','+
                          (line[3][1:]).upper()+','+line[4][1:]+','+line[5]+','+
                          line[6]+','+line[7]+','+line[8]+','+line[10])+'\n')
    out_csv.close()        
    
    print ("new .csv written")

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    
    for filepath in glob.iglob('C:\\Myfolder\\*.csv'):
        new_csv(filepath)
```

Comment: I am sorry @Anurag.K where should I add that iteration in the above code forgive me I am a beginner programmer

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you! @Anurag.k, it solved my problem, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your statements composing the string by adding commas is a bit clumsy.  Consider modifying the list so each field has what you want, then using `join` to put it all together:

```
def new_csv(file_path):
    out_csv = open(file_path.replace('.csv','_new.csv'), "w")
    for line in csv.reader(open(file_path)):
        line[2] = line[2].upper()
        line[3] = line[3][1:].upper()
        if len(line) == 10:
            line.pop(8)
        else:
            line[4] = line[4][1:]
            line.pop(9)
        print( ','.join(line), file=out_csv )
    out_csv.close()        
    
    print ("new .csv written")
```